# Does cycle.js and motorcycle.js have Typescript definitions?

Tags: cyclejs

I'm wondering if there are tsd definitions for cycle.js, motorcycle.js, most.js and snabbdom.

Answer (score 5):

No, not yet. But they will in an upcoming version (we are working on it currently).